# c# xml.Load() locking file on disk causing errors

Tags: c#, xml, locking, load

I have a simple class XmlFileHelper as follows:

```
public class XmlFileHelper
{
    #region Private Members

    private XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    private string xmlFilePath;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public XmlFileHelper(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        this.xmlFilePath = xmlFilePath;
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public XmlNode SelectSingleNode(string xPathQuery)
    {
        return xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPathQuery);
    }

    public string GetAttributeValueByName(XmlNode node, string attributeName)
    {
        return node.Attributes.GetNamedItem(attributeName).Value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public string XmlFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return xmlFilePath;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The issue is I am getting the following error on Load:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file ''C:\CvarUAT\ReportWriterSettings.xml'' **because it is being used by another process**
```

this occurs when this class is used to by two running instances of a component running in parallel both attempting to load the xml file above, this is legitimate behaviour and required by the application.

I only want to read in the xml off disk once and release any reference to the file on disk and use an in memory representation from that point forward.

I would have assumed Load operates in a readonly fashion and would have no need to lock the file, what is my best way to achieve the desired result and get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

it depends on what you need from the file,

If you need it to be threasdsafe you would need to impliment a mutex to lock the loading between instance,

If you dont really need thread safe loading (i.e. the file never changes) you could load it via a filestream then load the XmlDocument from the stream

```
            FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, FileMode.Open,
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 38):

You can do this

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(xmlFilePath))
{
    xmlDoc.Load(s);
}
```

instead of

```
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too big to read into memory all at once:

```
xml.Load(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)));
```

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
xml.Load(
       new StreamReader(
           new FileStream(
                  path, 
                  FileMode.Open, 
                  FileAccess.Read, 
                  FileShare.Read)
            )
          );
```

Comment: This method doesn't dispose the resources that are created.