# File being used by another process while reading config.xml from Skype

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
[ 10,13136] 2017-10-23T11:53:31 - -------------------- IOException caught --------------------
[ 10,13136] 2017-10-23T11:53:31 - The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\cdahal\AppData\Roaming\Skype\chetan.d\config.xml' because it is being used by another process.
[ 10,13136] 2017-10-23T11:53:31 - Stack trace is : 
[ 10,13136] 2017-10-23T11:53:31 -    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
```

Every time the Accessibility option in Skype is updated, it changes its config.xml file. We currently read values from the node /config/UI/General/Accessibility, however when my application and skype both are running and I make changes to the Accessibility option, I get the following error message:-

Comment: so you're trying to update skypes config, while its running and are surprised that its locking its config file?

Comment: What is your question? Simply put, if Skype has the file open and locked you cannot modify it.

Comment: Well, I am trying to read the updated values. Possible solutions would be copying the config.xml file to a temp location and trying to access. Was wondering if there might be any other solutions to it..

Comment: Youve got no code here - how are you opening the file to read values?

Comment: Are you using FileShare.Read and FIleAccess.Read when you open the file? Post your file opening code!

Comment: XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/config/UI/General/Accessibility");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say it, but I infer you are using XmlDocument.Load to load the file. You should try loading the document from a stream that has been opened with FileAccess.Read and FileShare.Read. This is a duplicate of [c# xml.Load() locking file on disk causing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812598/c-sharp-xml-load-locking-file-on-disk-causing-errors).